# Checking the Difference between 2 sheets and highlight the difference with the column saying "Difference"?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have 2 sheets with one offline data and one online data from a DB server and want to sort the difference between the two sheets and highlight the difference and count the difference and display the counting value in the end column if its there else have to say "same" in the end column.
 For eg: Sheet 1

```
   A   B  C  D  
   T1  T2 T3 T4  
   T1  T2 T3 T4
```

Sheet 2

```
   A   B  C  D       
   T1  T2 T3 T4   
   T1  T2 T4 T5
```

Result--> sheet 3 should be

```
   A   B  C  D     E  
   T1  T2 T3 T4  
   T1  T2 T3 T4    Same  
   T1  T2 T3 T4  
   T1  T2 T4 T5    2 difference
```

The Code i have is highlighting the difference but not Pasting the Sheet 1 value in the Sheet 3.My end result will be comparing the Same row and cell between the Sheet1 snd Sheet2 and have to paste the difference in the sheet 3 with pasting both rows consecutively. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Sub Compare()
Dim ColumnCount, RowCount As Long
 Dim w As Worksheet, r As Range

'Clearing the contents of the third sheet for the fresh comparison

usedCoulms = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").UsedRange.Columns.Count
usedRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To usedRows
For j = 1 To usedCoulms
   Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, j).Value = ""
  Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Next
Next

'Coulmn count of first sheet
ColumnCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
'row count of first sheet
RowCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To RowCount

For j = 1 To ColumnCount
     If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value <> Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j).Value Then    'Comparing if values are not equal
        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, j).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value  'Copying the Header of the Mismatched Cell
        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, j).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j).Value  'CStr("MisMatch")   'If mismatch setting set value as MisMatch
        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = 65535 'Highlighting with Yellow color
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, j).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j).Value
        'If values are same copy the first sheets value if dont want to copy can skip this
    End If

Next
Next
MsgBox "SORTINGCOMPLETE"
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't tag spam.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better and easier to have all data in same sheet, because you are comparing always same rows of both sheets. So I did this:

[image]

You compare row 2 of Sheet1 with row 2 of Sheet2, row3 with row 3, and so on...

Then,in the evaluation column, I have this formula:

```
=IF(4-SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:D2=F2:I2))>0;4-SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:D2=F2:I2))&" difference";"same")
```

As you can see, first comparison returns `same` because there are no differences. Second comparison (row 3) returns `2 difference` because there is only 2 matches.

To highlight the evaluation, just a conditional formatting rule. If the text **contains** the word `difference`, highlit it.

Hope you can adap this to your needs.